# Remove file using Runtime

Tags: java, android, runtime.exec

I tried to use this code to delete a file located into /data folder but it doesn't work, what's wrong in it? My device has root.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","rm"+" "+"/data/logger"});
```

SOLVED USING THIS

```
Process p;
            try {
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
                 os.writeBytes("rm /data/logger"+"\n");
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            p.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Generally, for `rm` to delete a non-empty directory you need the -r flag in possible addition to the -f one.  That would be apart from the issue of having a working "su" hack and passing arguments in a working way.

Comment: You should probably use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) because that will actually format your command correctly. And per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) - "ProcessBuilder.start() is now the preferred way to start a process with a modified environment."

Comment: Please give me an example with code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -f switch to force the delete.

File exists case is taken care by runtime class.

Try this:

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","rm","-f","/data/logger"});**

or this

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")**

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"rm","-f","/data/logger"});**

Comment: try to separate the su and rm logic .Are the files under logger or need to delete logger itself @Hasta'98